# use UCMA 3.0 to create a SIP client

Tags: sip, vxml, ucma

I am just wondering if UCMA 3.0 SDK supports this. 
I plan to use the SIP client to place a call to a standalone UCMA application, which will use VXML to play a prompt. Thanks.

Comment: Just to check - by the SIP client, do you mean Lync/Office communicator, or another SIP client? And by standalone, do you mean a UCMA app that isn't connected to Lync/OCS infrastructure? if so, what will it be connecting to?

Comment: 1. I mean a SIP client like XLite

Answer (score 3):

You need to provision an Application Endpoint first following General application activation steps.

Follow these steps using ucma 3.0 API after :

```
1) Create a new collaboration platform. Using 



X509Certificate2 cert ="your certificate thumb here";

 CollaborationPlatform _collabPlatform;

  ServerPlatformSettings settings = new ServerPlatformSettings(Name,  LocalhostFQDN,  ServicePort,  ServerGruu, cert);

 _collabPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(settings);
  _collabPlatform.AllowedAuthenticationProtocol = SipAuthenticationProtocols.Ntlm;
_collabPlatform.BeginStartup(PlatformStartupCompleted, _collabPlatform);

2) Create a new Endpoint.
Here is the callback.

         private void PlatformStartupCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
                 {

            try
            {
                _collabPlatform.EndStartup(result);

              ApplicationEndpointSettings settings = new ApplicationEndpointSettings( AgentUri,  ServerFQDN,  ServerPort);
                    // For registered endpoints (recommended).
                    settings.UseRegistration = true;
                    _localEndpoint = new ApplicationEndpoint(_collabPlatform, settings);

                    _localEndpoint.BeginEstablish(EndpointEstablishCompleted, null);

            }
            catch (ConnectionFailureException connFailEx)
            {
                // ConnectionFailureException will be thrown when the platform cannot connect. 

            }
            catch (RealTimeException rte)
            {
                // Any other RealTimeException could occur due to other error.

            }

            }
       }


         private void EndpointEstablishCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
             {
              _localEndpoint.EndEstablish(result);
             //Register Event for incoming call here.
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question correct, you want to create standalone ucma application which can play prompt when someone call using sip phone. Right? If so it is possible. For the sip phone you can use Phoner lite or xlite. But phoner lite does not support for call transferring. 
For create standalone application check this http://www.ksac.com/blog/bid/58799/UCMA-3-0-Programs-Without-Lync-Server